# Powershell profile script makes get-date loop, works when not part of script

Tags: powershell

Ok I am new but I didn't see any other questions like this.

All I am trying to do is make PS say "Some kinda greeting $date" when I open it.

First I just put `Get-Date` where `$date` is but that looped forever. Then I tried
`$date = Get-Date`
`Write-Host Welcome to powershell, today is $date` and that also looped forever.

I read the `Write-Host` may be an issue so I tried `Write-Output` and did the exact same thing.

So finally I tried adding a while loop with a counter and it did the exact same thing.
`$c=0`
`While ($c -lt 1){`
`Write-Host The date is (Get-Date)`
`$c++`
`}`
This all works if PS is already open or if I use the ISE but loops forever when it is in the profile script.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried this on Windows 10/PS5.1 and it seems to work as expected.  What version of OS/PowerShell are you using and which 'profile' are you adding the code to?  Is there anything else in the profile that might be causing a problem?

Comment: Hmmmm looks like 1909/ OS Build 18363.1440 and PS 5.1.18362.1171
Also thanks for responding!

Comment: Write-Host "Welcome to powershell, today is $date"  Notice the quotes!

Comment: @retiredgeek Unfortunately that seems to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the folks that tried to help! It looks like I copy and pasted replacing one of the paths to a module that I wanted to load with the path to the profile causing the loop.